# Adding close button on tab header in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I created one extended tab control. In that tab control I want to put close button(as like chrome browser tab). How it will happen? Please give any suggestion. This following code I used for creating tab control

```
 public class ExtendedTabControl : TabControl
    {
        public ExtendedTabControl()
        {
            this.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

            this.Invalidate();
            BorderWidth =1;

        }
        public Color ActiveBorderColor { get; set; }
        public Color InactiveBorderColor { get; set; }
        public Color ActiveTabColor { get; set; }
        public Color InActiveTabColor { get; set; }
        public float BorderWidth { get; set; }


        protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
            //TabPages[this.SelectedIndex]

            this.Invalidate();
        }
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.TabCount; i++)
            {
                if (i != this.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    DrawTab(e.Graphics, i, false);
                }
            }
            //TabPages[this.SelectedIndex].BackColor = ActiveTabColor;
            DrawTab(e.Graphics, this.SelectedIndex, true);

        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnPaint(e);







        }
        private void DrawTab(Graphics g, int i, bool isSelected)
        {
            if (i < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            Rectangle rectangle = GetTabRect(i);
            if (isSelected)
            {
                rectangle.Height += 2;
            }

            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            Point p1 = new Point(rectangle.X + 20, rectangle.Y);
            Point p2 = new Point(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Size.Height);
            path.AddLine(p1, p2);
            Point p3 = new Point(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width, rectangle.Y);
            path.AddLine(p1, p3);
            Point p4 = new Point(rectangle.Left + rectangle.Width + 24, rectangle.Top + rectangle.Height);
            path.AddLine(p3, p4);
            path.AddLine(p4, p2);
            if (isSelected)
            {

                using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(ActiveTabColor))
                {
                    g.FillPath(brush, path);
                }

                using (Pen pen = new Pen(ActiveBorderColor, BorderWidth))
                {
                    DrawTabBorder(g, pen);
                }


            }
            else
            {  
                using (Brush brushI = new SolidBrush(InActiveTabColor))
                {
                    g.FillPath(brushI, path); 
                }
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(InactiveBorderColor, BorderWidth))
                {
                    DrawTabBorder(g, pen);
                }

            }

        }

        private void DrawTabBorder(Graphics g, Pen pen)
        {
            if (this.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            Rectangle selectedRectangel = GetTabRect(this.SelectedIndex);
            #region coment
            //selectedRectangel.Width -= 6;
            //selectedRectangel.X += 1;        
            //Point pRight = new Point(this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.X + this.SelectedTab.Width + 1,
                                     //this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.Y - 1);

            //Point pRightBottam = new Point(this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.X + this.SelectedTab.Width + 1,
                                           //this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.Y + this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Height + 1);
            //Point pLeftTabStart = new Point(selectedRectangel.X, pLeft.Y);
            //Point pLeftTabStop = new Point(selectedRectangel.X + selectedRectangel.Width + selectedRectangel.Height + 1 ,
#endregion

            Point pLeft = new Point(this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.X, this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.Y);

            Point pLeftBottam = new Point(this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.X - 1, 
                                          this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.Y + this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Height + 1);
            Point pt1 = selectedRectangel.Location;
            pt1.X += 20;
            Point pt2 = new Point(selectedRectangel.Location.X + selectedRectangel.Width + 1, 
                                   selectedRectangel.Location.Y + 1);
            Point pt3 = new Point(selectedRectangel.X, selectedRectangel.Y + selectedRectangel.Height);
            Point pt4 = new Point(selectedRectangel.Left+selectedRectangel.Width+24,
                                   selectedRectangel.Top+selectedRectangel.Height);
            Point pt6 = new Point(this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.X + this.SelectedTab.Width + 1,
                                  this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Location.Y - 1);
            Point pt7 = new Point(pLeftBottam.X+this.SelectedTab.Bounds.Width,pLeftBottam.Y);
            Point pt8 = pLeftBottam;

            GraphicsPath pathTab = new GraphicsPath();
            pathTab.AddLine(pt3, pt1);
            pathTab.AddLine(pt1, pt2);
            pathTab.AddLine(pt2, pt4);
            pathTab.AddLine(pt4, pt6);
            pathTab.AddLine(pt6, pt7);
            pathTab.AddLine(pt7, pt8);
            pathTab.AddLine(pt8, pLeft);
            pathTab.AddLine(pLeft, pt3);

            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            pathTab.Widen(pen);
            g.DrawPath(pen, pathTab);



        }
        protected override void OnSelected(TabControlEventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage page = this.SelectedTab;
            page.BackColor = ActiveTabColor;
        }
}
```

Comment: if possible please give me some code snippet

Comment: i understood that answer but how i add close image to tab header.i didn't understand that concept.please tell me where and how i add image on tab header